# Regex isn't working properly with PHP or not getting how to implement this

Tags: php, regex

There is something really I couldn't understand is how can I check my previous match with the next character and set starting and ending character please guys help me.

**Here is an Example of my string**

```
..A..B..A...B.A.B
```

What I'm trying to do is starting of string:

1=> Check the first character is `..` or `A`

2=> and the Second thing is String cannot be like this `..A..A` it must be like `..A..B..` and sequence.

3=> Ending character must be `..` or `B` and won't be `A`

However, I can match the first character like so `^([A]{1}|[.]{1,100})` But when I'm trying this same way with ending character it is not working and I'm not getting how to do the step `2`.

Save my day guys. Thanks

Failed Regex: `^[\.{1,40}|A{1}]+(?!A)+(B)+(?!B)+(B|\.{1,40})$`

Comment: What's the bigger picture? Does rule 2 mean the 2nd character in a string or the first character after .. or A? If there's a less contrived example, there might be a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm just messing with it and not getting any good solution :( @mkaatman

Comment: I tried to match starting index with `^` this can be either `.{1,40}` Or `A` and then the second capture group is  I said to check the next character and don't match the `A` again and like the same I repeated for `B`

Comment: A character class is a list of allowed characters. Can you explain what your trying to do a bit more? How many `.`s should there be prior to the A, how many after, after the second separator it should be sequential or just not the previous character? Are the separators `..` always the same interval? Could you please add 3-4 sample strings.

Comment: Is `A..B..A...B.A.B` acceptable since first character is `A`. Please provide some more valid matches.

Comment: @chris85 I know that but the thing I'm trying look ahead by `+` sign but I think it is not working properly. How can I look for next element that it is the character I want to match.

Comment: Some valid sets: `A..B..A.....B`, `....`, `A....B............`, Some Invalid sets: `B......A..`, `..A....A...B`, `B..A`, `B....B....B..A` i hope this will help @chris85

Comment: @Smalldeveloper: You said **_Ending character must be .._** but your examples are contradictory. Please update your question with valid matches.

Comment: it is A then B always @chris55

Comment: @Rahul Please check I said Ending character must be `..` Or `B` anyone can be from two of.

Comment: @Smalldeveloper: How is **....** valid ?

Comment: @chris85: Your solution is not matching two cases. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/OUJxxc/2/)

Comment: @chris85  Thank you, so much for unpredictable effort :)

Comment: @Rahul Thank you, so much for unpredictable effort :)

Comment: Yes your Last update just worked Perfectly :) @chris85

Comment: @chris85: Your's is elegant. Don't know why I made it so complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should match the description you've given:

```
^(?:\.+?)?(A\.+?B\.?|\.\.)+$
```

`^` is the start of the string (or line if `m` modifier is used).
`(?:\.+?)?` is one or more `.`, but it optional.
`A\.+B\.?` is looking for an `A` any amount of `.`s then a `B` and an optional `.`.
`|` is an alternative pattern we'll look at
`\.\.` are 2 `.`s
`+` allows for the whole group to occur once or more
`$` is the end of the string (or line, again depends on modifier being used)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OUJxxc/3/ (Probably with a clearer description than I provided)

Comment: What do you mean `HT` pattern? Please add an example.

Comment: like this `A..B..A.....B
....
A....B............
..A..B..A...B.A.B
A..B..A...B.A.B
A..B..A.....B
....
A....B............ ` like all those pattern this `AB` should be also valid

Comment: What is "HT" whitespace?

Comment: Oh Sorry Really sorry I meant `HT` is `AB` . `AB` is also should be valid regex

Comment: Your losing me, your sample is a typo and `A` should be `H` and `B` should be `T`?

Comment: Yes you got it @chris

Comment: You should be able to do it with an alteration `|` in my pattern, give it a try.

Comment: Great and now you've learned some regex skills hopefully too. (My approach, https://regex101.com/r/OUJxxc/4/)

Comment: Chris, can you tell us some practical way of learning this regex? and some real life examples where i can find the explanation like u explained on answer

Comment: This is getting a bit broad. I find alterations, quantifiers, ranges, anchors, and character classes to be the most useful. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good site as is http://www.rexegg.com/.

Comment: If i had access then i would give you 5 upvote in one click :D

Comment: Also note regex usages vary with the language `mysql` for example uses POSIX, where as PHP uses `PCRE` so `\d` works in PHP but not in mysql, mysql equivalent is `[0-9]` (which also would work in PHP, just a bit longer). Good luck with your regexing.